# Why do flax eggs make my bread mushy?

Tags: food, cooking

I've been trying to bake bread using homemade flax eggs, but every time I do, the inside of the bread is mushy and uncooked. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: what kind of bread are you making that requires an egg substitute? Can you elaborate on your method please?

Comment: Neither of them required it. I only wanted to experiment. The first attempt was with paleo sandwich bread recipe and the other was with 90s low carb keto bread. https://gimmedelicious.com/90-second-keto-bread/ | https://www.paleorunningmomma.com/paleo-sandwich-bread/

Comment: I am unwilling to answer but I would suggest that the problem is that you are adding water to the recipe in the form of the flax eggs. The flax will retain the water and that will increase the cooking time or make it too difficult to cook the bread evenly. Can you manage to add less water? Also, flax may not be the best substitute for the eggs in these recipes (both of them do call for eggs). I would suggest trying dried gluten flour but both of these recipes are strenuously wheat-avoiding haha

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Some good information on egg replacers here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20830/egg-replacer-for-bread-dough

In my own vegan/gluten-free bread baking, I swear by Bob's Red Mill egg replacement.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that eggs serve a different purpose in the recipes you experimented with.

Eggs can be either a leavening agent, emulsifier, thickener, binder, coat and sealer, or  color and shine.  ([source](https://www.eggs.ca/eggs101/view/95/food-science))

From the recipes you posted, it looks like one was more of a leavening need (90 second recipe) and the other was more for moistness (sandwich bread recipe).

Gluten free bread calls for eggs because...

> Eggs are natural leaveners that help boost the rise and volume of bread. Eggs also add moisture, flavor, and protein to gluten-free bread recipes. If you select a gluten-free bread recipe that includes eggs, you have a better chance that the resulting bread will have good color, more volume, and softer texture. Eggs also help to extend the shelf-life of gluten-free bread, which can become stale more quickly than wheat bread.
> https://www.thespruceeats.com/tips-for-better-gluten-free-bread-1451069

Flax eggs appear to be best used for binding because they don't offer much structural support ([source](https://cookieandkate.com/flax-egg-recipe/#:%7E:text=Flax%20eggs%20work%20well%20when,fat%2C%20like%20real%20yolks%20do.)).